# asp C# write csv file to client hangs on download

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, csv, httpresponse

I'm trying to output a CSV file to the client. When the save dialog comes up ( in both Internet Explorer 10 & Google Chrome ) and I try to open it from the browser, the file hangs and is stuck in "Running Security Scan". However, I am able to save the file without an problems. Below is the code I'm using to generate the file. Also to note, I have tried `HttpContext.Current.Response.End();` and `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();` and got the same result. Please help

```
        string attachment = "attachment; filename=" + "MyCSVFile.csv";
        var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;

        response.Clear();
        response.ClearHeaders();
        response.ClearContent();
        response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
        response.ContentType = "text/csv";

        var csv = new StringBuilder();
        // ... Build contents for csv file

        response.Write(csv.ToString());
        response.End();
```

Comment: Does this security scan occure on every download not only from your website? Please try do disable Smart Screen Filter to check if it  holds downloadings http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/smartscreen-filter-frequently-asked-questions-ie9

Comment: Does the client download any bytes when you inspect the downloaded file?

Comment: Yes it does, it downloads it fully but gets stuck on the scan. The same thing happens on google chrome. I can see all the bytes downloaded but the file never opens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the issue had nothing to do with my code but rather a corrupt file in Windows. I fixed this by opening command prompt with `Run as Administrator` and running the command `sfc/scannow`. It now downloads and opens correctly.